# QR code scanner with Raspberry Pi3

Tags: camera

I was to use the Raspberry Pi3 and iBall camera to scan QR code. I am totally new to this domain. I have 8 years of experience in Embedded C coding. Can anyone let me know how to start, what all things will I need and if there is any free stack available for same in C language?

Your replies will definitely help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

For QR Code readers, I have had some success with xZing, its quite fast and can be found here. https://github.com/zxing/zxing

To keep things simple, you just need to pass a raw image and you get the contents of the barcode. The c# example below is gives simple illustration,   I'm pretty sure the c/c++ port is just as easy to use.

```
// create a barcode reader instance
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
// load a bitmap
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.LoadFrom("C:\\sample-barcode-image.png");

// detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);

// do something with the result
if (result != null)
{
   txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
   txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
}
```

Code above from https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Start with a block diagram with the capabilities.  Start with taking a photo of the target.  For example:

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
fswebcam test.jpg
```

If successful then you can consider writing a routine in C to pull images for image processing from [**OpenCV**](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/).

I have yet to see free barcode reader source code: if you find this Unicorn, be sure to post a link to it for others.

Unless this is a pedagogical exercise, building this a barcode scanner from a camera is a lot of work when you can simply buy a [**USB scanner for $20**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00406YZGK).  The capture and decode functionality is baked into the USB scanner.  You can either use existing [**Python evdev**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732978/how-can-i-get-a-string-from-hid-device-in-python-with-evdev) to read the characters or 'roll your own' in C. Python was fast and  the route that  others have successfully and quickly navigated